# How to make a correct contour plot of `Arg[z]`?

Tags: plotting

Let $z \in \mathbb C$ be an arbitrary complex number. Call it

- Red, if $\Im(z^7) > 0$
- Blue, if $\Im(z^7) < 0$
- Gray, if $\Im(z^7) = 0$.

I want to make a plot in which the red, blue and gray regions of the complex plane are painted in the appropriate color. I have the following helper function:

```
proc[f_, r_] := ComplexContourPlot[f, {z, 2},
  Contours -> r, ContourShading -> {LightBlue, LightPink}];
```

The naïve way to use this function is

```
proc[Im[z^7], {0}]
```

This does not work as nicely as one would hope. The plot is distorted near the origin due to numerical stability issues in the calculation of $\Im(z^7)$ for very small $z$.

Another attempt would be

```
r = Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/7];
proc[Arg[z], r]
```

This almost works, but not quite. The negative real axis is not painted correctly. This behavior is not unexpected, because `Arg[z]` is discontinuous at the negative real axis. But it is still annoying.

One rather ugly way to make this work is

```
p1 = proc[Arg[z], r];
p2 = proc[Arg[-z], {0}];
Show[p2, p1]
```

Is there anything less egregious than this that will still work?

Comment: Is cranking up `PlotPoints` not an option?  I don't have MM 12, so I can't use `ComplexContourPlot`, but using `ContourPlot[Im[(x + I y)^7], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]` in MM 11 seems to give a reasonable result.

Comment: Building off @Michael's proposal, here's one way to color it: `ContourPlot[Im[(x + I y)^7], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Gray, Red}, LogisticSigmoid[10 #]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If processing time is not a concern, the option `PlotPoints` can be used to force Mathematica to perform more sampling of the function being plotted.

```
ComplexContourPlot[f, {z, 2},  Contours -> r, 
 ContourShading -> {LightBlue, LightPink}, PlotPoints->100]
```

(Please note:  I have not tried this code, as I do not have MM 12.  If it does not work, please let me know.)

Comment: It does work, thanks!